# Q: Windows 10 Recycle Bin icon "glitch"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, recycle-bin

ICON:

[image]

BIN WINDOW:

[image]

ICON SETTINGS:

[image]

PROPERTIES:

[image]

This happened few days ago. I've checked every fix out there and they don't seem to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fix , yall just have to run the reg file and everything will be fixed ! http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/259130d1363202038-empty-recycle-bin-add-desktop-context-menu-add_empty_recycle_bin_to_recycle_bin_context_menu.reg